# How to get Data received in response superagent

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, superagent

I am trying to hit an api and want to get the data received in response.

For this purpose I am using superagent, I am getting the data from the api and I have checked in my network tab,but the problem is,
I want the data that I got in my response network tab,but I am getting the whole network tab data instead of only response data.Here below is my code

```
  check=(evt)=>{

    evt.preventDefault();

    agent
        .get(`https://mws.amazonservices.com/Finances/2015-05-01`)
        .query({
            AWSAccessKeyId:'AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE',
            Action:'GetServiceStatus',
            SellerId:'A13LAO8KHSSL',
            MWSAuthToken:'533644733019',
            SignatureVersion:2,
            Timestamp:'2019-05-16T05:55:43Z',
            Version:'2015-05-01',
            Signature:'wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY',
            SignatureMethod:'HmacSHA256'
        })
        .then(res => {
           console.log('here is the response');
            console.log(res)  // here it print the whole data I only need data got in //response
      })
      };
```

How can I only get data of response

Comment: Do not share your keys, and also post what response that you are getting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SuperAgent returns an object with the request and response details, for example the `status` and `text`. If you want to have the raw response body, use the `text` property:

```
agent
    .get(...)
    .query(...)
    .then(response => {
        const rawBody = response.text;
        console.log(rawBody);
    });
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<GetServiceStatusResponse>
   ...
</GetServiceStatusResponse>
```